# Regex module error when join a set of regex using pipes

Tags: python, regex

For performance purposes, I've tried to transform a set of regexes into only one using pipes.

```
   self.regexes_token = [
                {'descricao':'site www.', 'regex': r'^www\.(.+?)$'},
                {'descricao':'apenas pontuacao','regex':r'^[[:punct:]]+?$'},
                {'descricao':'palavra com sinal negativo', 'regex': r'^(-)(.*?)$', 'grupo': r'\2'},
                {'descricao':'pronomes e títulos', 'regex': r'^(sra?|exm[º|°|o]|dr[a|ª]?|(v\.)?ex\.?(a|ª)\.?)\.??$'},
                {'descricao':'oab sigla', 'regex': r'^oab\/[a-z]{2}$'},
                {'descricao':'termos irrelevantes', 'regex': r'^(s\/n|e\/ou|e-?mail|cep|rj|tel\.?(\/fax|efone)?|anos?|rua|cpf|www)\.?$'},
                {'descricao':'chassi (VIN)', 'regex': r'^[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{9}[\d+]{5}$'},
                {'descricao':'data_br', 'regex': r'^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$'},
                {'descricao':'um char e ponto', 'regex': r'^\w[[:punct:]]$'},
                {'descricao':'rg','regex': r'^\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d(\/.*)?'},
                {'descricao':'unidades de medidas', 'regex': r'^(\d{1,2},?x?)+(cm|m(l|²|2|m)?|k(g|m))$'},
                {'descricao':'zero seguido de qualquer coisa', 'regex': r'^0(.*)$'},
                {'descricao':'::punct:: seguido de qualquer coisa','regex':r'^[[:punct:]](.+?)$'},
                {'descricao':'telefone avulso', 'regex': r'^\d{4,5}-\d{4}$'},
                {'descricao':'ano', 'regex': r'\b(19|20)\d{2}\.?\b'},
                {'descricao':'contém char especial', 'regex': r'^.*?(~|\^|¿|¡|>|<|»|#|£|\?|»|·|#|\*|=|\+|¥|€|\||µ|®)+.*?$'}
            ]
            
            
            self.regexes_token_union = r'('+'|'.join([d['regex'] for d in self.regexes_token])+r')'
            print(self.regexes_token_union)
```

Follow regex:

```
(^www\.(.+?)$|^[[:punct:]]+?$|^(-)(.*?)$|^(sra?|exm[º|°|o]|dr[a|ª]?|(v\.)?ex\.?(a|ª)\.?)\.??$|^oab\/[a-z]{2}$|^(s\/n|e\/ou|e-?mail|cep|rj|tel\.?(\/fax|efone)?|anos?|rua|cpf|www)\.?$|^[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{9}[\d+]{5}$|^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^\w[[:punct:]]$|^\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d(\/.*)?|^(\d{1,2},?x?)+(cm|m(l|²|2|m)?|k(g|m))$|^0(.*)$|^[[:punct:]](.+?)$|^\d{4,5}-\d{4}$|\b(19|20)\d{2}\.?\b|^.*?(~|\^|¿|¡|>|<|»|#|£|\?|»|·|#|\*|=|\+|¥|€|\||µ|®)+.*?$)
```

But when I've tried to run (compile), python's regex module (not re) got an error:

```
regex._regex_core.error: cannot refer to an open group at position 272
```

I've used notepad++ to see the "col" position but even then I was not able to detect what opened group is this

The "confusing thing" is that when I run each regex on a loop, it's works fine (but the performance is not good)

So, how can I fix this?

Comment: Note the backreferences you have in the regexps are messed up in the resulting big regex.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem. Do your union on the first 3 expressions, then the first 4, etc. until you get an error. That should at least narrow down the expression that is giving you trouble.

Comment: For what it's worth you get the same error with stock `re`; but you really should turn your code into a [mre] so we don't have to guess how you are trying to compile the regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental error here is that when you combine the regular expressions with `|`, the group operator `\2` will not refer to the second group *in the expression which tried to refer to it,* but to the second parenthesized group in the combined regular expression.

A partial fix is to use non-grouping parentheses everywhere except where you really need to refer back to a group. A better fix is to define *named* groups where you need them, so you can refer back to them by name instead of by number.

The actual error message is trying to say that in

```
r'^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1...
```

you can't use `\1` because the group started with the first open parenthesis is not yet defined, because we haven't seen its closing parenthesis yet.  The overall first group is the one you started with `r'(' + '|'.join(...) + r')'` so minimally you'd have to renumber this to match the numbering of the combined regex -- but again, that's almost unmaintainable, and easy to avoid with named groups (at least up to a point; if you have a lot of named groups, keeping track of name clashes etc also becomes a problem).

*Probably* you are trying to refer back to the captured date separator? If so, try

```
r'^(?:(?:31(?P<sep>[-/.])(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))(?P=sep)...
```

where I also simplified the capturing expression by using a character class.

Tangentially, there is no need to backslash slashes -- the slash is not a regex metacharacter at all, so it simply matches itself. Notice also how inside a character class you just have a list of characters, so those should not be separated by `|` (you include `|` once if you want to match a literal `|` of course, but that does not seem to be the case in your examples).

Here is a pretty mechanical refactoring of your definition with all grouping parentheses replaced with non-grouping ones, and replacing groups with named groups where I was hopefully able to correctly guess what the groups should match, as well as correcting the simple beginner errors relating to slashes and character classes. There was also one superfluous `{1}` -- obviously a single instance of a character already matches itself exactly, and you don't have to spell out that there is one of it.  (Also wondering whether `[1,3-9]` should perhaps be `[13-9]`?)

```py
        self.regexes_token = [
                {'descricao':'site www.', 'regex': r'^www\.(?:.+?)$'},
                {'descricao':'apenas pontuacao','regex':r'^[[:punct:]]+?$'},
                {'descricao':'palavra com sinal negativo', 'regex': r'^(?:-)(?P<palavra>.*?)$', 'grupo': 'palavra'},
                {'descricao':'pronomes e títulos', 'regex': r'^(?:sra?|exm[º°o]|dr[aª]?|(?:v\.)?ex\.?[aª]\.?)\.??$'},
                {'descricao':'oab sigla', 'regex': r'^oab/[a-z]{2}$'},
                {'descricao':'termos irrelevantes', 'regex': r'^(?:s/n|e/ou|e-?mail|cep|rj|tel\.?(?:/fax|efone)?|anos?|rua|cpf|www)\.?$'},
                {'descricao':'chassi (VIN)', 'regex': r'^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{9}[\d+]{5}$'},
                {'descricao':'data_br', 'regex': r'(?:(?:31(?P<sep>/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))(?P=sep)|(?:(?:29|30)(?P<sep2>/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(?P=sep2)))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(?P<sep3>/|-|\.)0?2(?P=sep3)(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(?P<sep4>/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?P=sep4)(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$'},
                {'descricao':'um char e ponto', 'regex': r'^\w[[:punct:]]$'},
                {'descricao':'rg','regex': r'^\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d(?:/.*)?'},
                {'descricao':'unidades de medidas', 'regex': r'^(?:\d{1,2},?x?)+(?:cm|m[l²2m]?|k[gm])$'},
                {'descricao':'zero seguido de qualquer coisa', 'regex': r'^0(?:.*)$'},
                {'descricao':'::punct:: seguido de qualquer coisa','regex':r'^[[:punct:]](?:.+?)$'},
                {'descricao':'telefone avulso', 'regex': r'^\d{4,5}-\d{4}$'},
                {'descricao':'ano', 'regex': r'\b(?:19|20)\d{2}\.?\b'},
                {'descricao':'contém char especial', 'regex': r'^.*?[~^|¿¡><»#£?»·*=+¥€\\µ®]+.*?$'}
            ]

            self.regexes_token_union = r'|'.join([d['regex'] for d in self.regexes_token])
```

There is actually no need to use parentheses around the union expression; they don't add anything.

Notice also how I replaced `'grupo': r'\2'` with `'grupo': 'palavra'` after also naming the corresponding group -- you will obviously need to adapt the code which tries to use that group to instead pull out the named group via [`groupdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict).

Embedding long and complicated regular expressions like these in a single block of code is really unmaintainable. I have not tried to refactor the code further because I do not pretend to understand it; but as a start, you might want to split up the humongous regex and split it over several lines, something like

```
                {'descricao':'data_br',
                 'regex': r'(?:(?:31(?P<sep>/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))(?P=sep)|'
                          r'(?:(?:29|30)(?P<sep2>/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(?P=sep2)))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|'
                          r'^(?:29(?P<sep3>/|-|\.)0?2(?P=sep3)(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|'
                          r'(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(?P<sep4>/|-|\.)'
                          r'(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?P=sep4)(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$'
                },
```

Better yet still, use the `re.X` flag and write the regex over several lines with embedded comments.

Comment: The `\b` at the end of `ano` is probably also not doing what you hope, but there is so much guessing here already -- I would really urge you to update your question to focus on _just_ this problem, and review the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for further help.